# Custom rewriter for json

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

I am receiving a json string of the form

```json
{
  "people": [
    {
      "Freddie": {
        "surname": "Mercury",
        "city": "London"
      }
    },
    {
      "David": {
        "surname": "Bowie",
        "city": "Berlin"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

with the ultimate goal of recovering them as Proto messages of the kind

```
message Person {
  optional string name = 1;
  optional string surname = 2;
  optional string city = 3;
}

message Msg {
  repeated Person people = 1;
}
```

What is the best practice - i.e. short of custom adhoc logic of manipulating the keys - to convert the above json string to a string
sich as

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Freddie",
      "surname": "Mercury",
      "city": "London"
    },
    {
      "name": "David",
      "surname": "Bowie",
      "city": "Berlin"
    }
  ]
}
```

so that the correspondence between the json
and the Proto is one-to-one, and therefore out-of-the-box deserializers could be used?

Comment: (1) Custom JSON marshaler; (2) Use default JSON marshaler and define mappings between the JSON-equivalent types and the Protobuf types. The first option is potentially more efficient in that there's one iteration across the messages but there's a potential issue in your types. The Protobuf schema does not prohibited duplicate `name`'s but the JSON does e.g. "Freddie Kruger" and "Freddie Mercury".